# What is the magic under Spock "then" block?

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm new to Groovy/Spock, and curious to understand the undercover of the "then" block syntax :

```
def "my specification"() {
    given:
        int a = 1
    when:
        ++a
    then:
        a == 1
        a > 0
        a != 2
}
```

How does the framework evaluate separately the 3 last lines of this method ?

Comment: There's a really good blog post by @szymon-stepniak which goes in to great detail about what spock does to the then block: https://e.printstacktrace.blog/spock-assertion-inside-if-statement-doesnt-work-why/

Comment: This is a good reading. I'm taking a look to compiled code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates) and [injecteer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1682820/injecteer) said, here is the result of Fernflower decompilation (done in IntelliJ IDEA) of the following specification:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Specification

class DummyTest extends Specification {
  def "my specification"() {
    given:
    int a = 1
    when:
    ++a
    then:
    a == 2
    a > 1
    a != 3
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.BytecodeInterface8;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation;
import org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorCollector;
import org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime;
import org.spockframework.runtime.ValueRecorder;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockMetadata;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureMetadata;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.SpecMetadata;
import spock.lang.Specification;

@SpecMetadata(
  filename = "DummyTest.groovy",
  line = 5
)
public class DummyTest extends Specification implements GroovyObject {
  public DummyTest() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    super();
  }

  @FeatureMetadata(
    line = 6,
    name = "my specification",
    ordinal = 0,
    blocks = {@BlockMetadata(
  kind = BlockKind.SETUP,
  texts = {}
), @BlockMetadata(
  kind = BlockKind.WHEN,
  texts = {}
), @BlockMetadata(
  kind = BlockKind.THEN,
  texts = {}
)},
    parameterNames = {}
  )
  public void $spock_feature_0_0() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    ErrorCollector $spock_errorCollector = (ErrorCollector)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[0].callConstructor(ErrorCollector.class, false), ErrorCollector.class);
    ValueRecorder $spock_valueRecorder = (ValueRecorder)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[1].callConstructor(ValueRecorder.class), ValueRecorder.class);

    Object var10000;
    try {
      int a = 1;
      int a;
      if (BytecodeInterface8.isOrigInt() && !__$stMC && !BytecodeInterface8.disabledStandardMetaClass()) {
        a = a + 1;
      } else {
        a = DefaultTypeTransformation.intUnbox(var1[2].call(Integer.valueOf(a)));
      }

      try {
        SpockRuntime.verifyCondition($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder.reset(), "a == 2", Integer.valueOf(12), Integer.valueOf(5), (Object)null, $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(2)), ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual($spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(0)), a), $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(1)), 2))));
        var10000 = null;
      } catch (Throwable var44) {
        SpockRuntime.conditionFailedWithException($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder, "a == 2", Integer.valueOf(12), Integer.valueOf(5), (Object)null, var44);
        var10000 = null;
      } finally {
        ;
      }

      try {
        SpockRuntime.verifyCondition($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder.reset(), "a > 1", Integer.valueOf(13), Integer.valueOf(5), (Object)null, $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(2)), ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareGreaterThan($spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(0)), a), $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(1)), 1))));
        var10000 = null;
      } catch (Throwable var42) {
        SpockRuntime.conditionFailedWithException($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder, "a > 1", Integer.valueOf(13), Integer.valueOf(5), (Object)null, var42);
        var10000 = null;
      } finally {
        ;
      }

      try {
        SpockRuntime.verifyCondition($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder.reset(), "a != 3", Integer.valueOf(14), Integer.valueOf(5), (Object)null, $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(2)), ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareNotEqual($spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(0)), a), $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(Integer.valueOf(1)), 3))));
        var10000 = null;
      } catch (Throwable var40) {
        SpockRuntime.conditionFailedWithException($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder, "a != 3", Integer.valueOf(14), Integer.valueOf(5), (Object)null, var40);
        var10000 = null;
      } finally {
        ;
      }

      var1[3].call(var1[4].call(this.getSpecificationContext()));
    } finally {
      $spock_errorCollector.validateCollectedErrors();
      var10000 = null;
    }

  }
}
```

Tim's link gives you more background information. As you see there is more than just prepending `assert`, it is more like `SpockRuntime.verifyCondition(..)` wrapped in try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

`then` itself is a plain old Java label.

Each line is a new call >> Java's `;` can be ommitted.

Each call is wrapped inside Groovy's `assert` statement, which can be also executed outside Spock:

```
int a = 1
assert a
assert 0 < a
assert !a // here assertion error
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Could you precise how the wrapping occurs ?

Comment: @injecteer 'Each call is wrapped inside Groovy's assert statement' is a good approximation but not totally true, see kriegaex answer for what actually happens. Spock has its own power assertions, which are similar but not quite the same as the groovy one.

Answer (score 0):

There are several excellent answers, from different aspects of the implementation. I will provide yet another answer from how to parse the Spock syntax, with links to source code.

First of all, the syntax is a simple ["label"](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_labeled_statements). The official doc shows that labels are used similar to ancient C labels in `goto`. A statement can have [label(s)](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/stmt/Statement.html#getStatementLabels()). It is a syntax sugar and Spock uses it to provide straightforward DSL syntax.

The groovy source code is processed (parsed) by groovy compiler and the source code is transformed into AST. This is already a valid groovy program but it cannot do what you expect it to do. Spock needs to another transform (rewrite) to add unit testing features to the syntax. Spock writes the "glue code" for you.

The Spock's spec visitor uses [`buildBlocks()`](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/e37581be676ae277afb048e7aa9b5bb599ccc8b3/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/compiler/SpecParser.java#L194) to check labels and decides to build a block in AST for later rewrite.

After that, a rewriter will [re-visit the AST (in your case `visitThenBlock()`)](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/e37581be676ae277afb048e7aa9b5bb599ccc8b3/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/compiler/SpecRewriter.java#L396) to generate code as other answers have shown. The rewriter checks `then` block to ensure that [statements|expressions in the block are asserts](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/e37581be676ae277afb048e7aa9b5bb599ccc8b3/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/compiler/DeepBlockRewriter.java#L61) or [implicit conditions](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/e37581be676ae277afb048e7aa9b5bb599ccc8b3/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/compiler/DeepBlockRewriter.java#L192).